# OpenCV - Filter blobs by width and height

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a image filtered by canny edge detector. Now, i want to detect blobs and do some filter by width and height. What are the functions that i have to look at ?

Comment: [connectedComponentsWithStats](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=connectedcomponents#connectedcomponents) includes `width` and `height` of each connected component in the returned `stats` array. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: *Note - `connectedComponents` and `connectedComponentsWithStats` are only available in OpenCV 3.0.

Comment: Oh, that's nice. Looking at the documentation, yes, this would be it. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. If you don't mind, I'll post it as an answer for future googlers. I just wasn't sure before that this was what you were looking for.

Answer (score 4):

an alternative approach based on [minAreaRect](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga3d476a3417130ae5154aea421ca7ead9&gsc.tab=0) of contours and distance between minAreaRect points. by this way it is possible to filter contours by their angles as seen on sample result image.

you can change width & height ratio and angel by changing following lines

```
if(dist0 > dist1 *4) // dist0 and dist1 means width and height you can change as you wish
.
.
if( fabs(angle) > 35 & fabs(angle) < 150 ) // you can change angle criteria
```

[image]
[image]

```
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

//! Compute the distance between two points
/*! Compute the Euclidean distance between two points
*
* @param a Point a
* @param b Point b
*/
static double distanceBtwPoints(const cv::Point2f &a, const cv::Point2f &b)
{
    double xDiff = a.x - b.x;
    double yDiff = a.y - b.y;

    return std::sqrt((xDiff * xDiff) + (yDiff * yDiff));
}

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    Mat src,gray;
    src = imread(argv[1]);
    if(src.empty())
        return -1;

    cvtColor( src, gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY );
    gray = gray < 200;

    vector<vector<Point> > contours;

    findContours(gray.clone(), contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

    RotatedRect _minAreaRect;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); ++i)
    {
        _minAreaRect = minAreaRect( Mat(contours[i]) );
        Point2f pts[4];
        _minAreaRect.points(pts);

        double dist0 = distanceBtwPoints(pts[0], pts[1]);
        double dist1 = distanceBtwPoints(pts[1], pts[2]);

        double angle = 0;
        if(dist0 > dist1 *4)
            angle =atan2(pts[0].y - pts[1].y,pts[0].x - pts[1].x) * 180.0 / CV_PI;
        if(dist1 > dist0 *4)
            angle =atan2(pts[1].y - pts[2].y,pts[1].x - pts[2].x) * 180.0 / CV_PI;

        if( fabs(angle) > 35 & fabs(angle) < 150 )
            for( int j = 0; j < 4; j++ )
                line(src, pts[j], pts[(j+1)%4], Scalar(0, 0, 255), 1, LINE_AA);
    }
    imshow("result", src);
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In OpenCV 3.0 you can use [`connectedComponentsWithStats`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=connectedcomponents#connectedcomponents) which returns a `stats` array which includes the width and height of each connected component:

> statsv –
>
> statistics output for each label, including the background label, see below for available statistics. Statistics are accessed via statsv(label, COLUMN) where available columns are defined below.
>
> - CC_STAT_LEFT The leftmost (x) coordinate which is the inclusive start
>   of the bounding box in the horizontal direction.
> - CC_STAT_TOP The topmost (y) coordinate which is the inclusive start of the bounding box in the vertical direction.
> - CC_STAT_WIDTH The horizontal size of the bounding box
> - CC_STAT_HEIGHT The vertical size of the bounding box
> - CC_STAT_AREA The total area (in pixels) of the connected component

Comment: I don't mind at all. openCV 3 has a lot of new and cool stuff