# OpenCV2 - Narrow Rectangles found using SimpleBlobDetector, but can't extract the angle

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to get the angle of the middle line in a domino. SimpleBlobDetector can find it, but it gives me an angle value of -1.
Does anyone know why that can be? and how can i fix that still using SimpleBlobDetector? and if SimpleBlobDetector is not an option, what else can i do to find the center and angle of these lines?

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os
import time
#from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def main():
    capWebcam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)         # declare a VideoCapture object and associate to webcam, 0 => use 1st webcam

    params = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_Params()
    params.filterByCircularity = True
    params.minCircularity = 0.73

    params2 = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_Params()
    params2.filterByInertia = True
    params2.maxInertiaRatio = 0.3

                    # show original resolution
    print "default resolution = " + str(capWebcam.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)) + "x" + str(capWebcam.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))

    capWebcam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 320.0)              # change resolution to 320x240 for faster processing
    capWebcam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 240.0)
    capWebcam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 1)


                                            # show updated resolution
    print "updated resolution = " + str(capWebcam.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)) + "x" + str(capWebcam.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))

    if capWebcam.isOpened() == False:               # check if VideoCapture object was associated to webcam successfully
        print "error: capWebcam not accessed successfully\n\n"      # if not, print error message to std out
        os.system("pause")                                          # pause until user presses a key so user can see error message
        return                                                      # and exit function (which exits program)
    # end if

    while cv2.waitKey(1) != 27 and capWebcam.isOpened():            # until the Esc key is pressed or webcam connection is lost
        blnFrameReadSuccessfully, img = capWebcam.read()            # read next frame

        if not blnFrameReadSuccessfully or img is None:     # if frame was not read successfully
            print "error: frame not read from webcam\n"             # print error message to std out
            os.system("pause")                                      # pause until user presses a key so user can see error message
            break                                                   # exit while loop (which exits program)

        det = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_create(params)
        det2 = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_create(params2)


        gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)



        time.sleep(0.1)
        keypts = det.detect(gray)
        time.sleep(0.1)
        keypts2 = det2.detect(gray)

        print len(keypts)
        print len(keypts2)

        for l in keypts2:
            print l.pt
            print l.angle                




        time.sleep(0.3)
        imgwk = cv2.drawKeypoints(gray, keypts, img,color= (200,0,139),flags=2)

        time.sleep(0.1)
        imgwk2 = cv2.drawKeypoints(img, keypts2, gray,color= (200,0,139),flags=2)



        cv2.namedWindow("img", cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)           # or use WINDOW_NORMAL to allow window resizing

        cv2.imshow("img", img)

                              # hold windows open until user presses a key

    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

    return


###################################################################################################
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if SimpleBlob detector is the best for this, but have you looked at

[Detect centre and angle of rectangles in an image using Opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34237253/detect-centre-and-angle-of-rectangles-in-an-image-using-opencv?rq=1)

It seems quite similar to you question, and seems to do very well at identifying the angle of the rectangles

Comment: I'll give this a try. Thanks :D

Comment: Do you have any idea how to convert this: '        cv::RotatedRect rotatedRect = cv::minAreaRect(contours[i]);

        // read points and angle
        cv::Point2f rect_points[4]; 
        rotatedRect.points( rect_points );

        float  angle = rotatedRect.angle; // angle

        // read center of rotated rect
        cv::Point2f center = rotatedRect.center; // center' to python?