# How to rotate the image to 180 degree always using minAreaRect, c++

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing, image-rotation

My Images;

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Requirement:

[image]

I am not able to understand how axis is decided to make the image always horizontal.

**Algorithm:**

- Read the image
- Find external contour
- Draw the contours
- Use the external contour to detect minArearect (bounding box will not help for me)
- get the rotation matrix and rotate the image
- Extract the required patch from the rotated image

My code:

```
//read the image
img = imread("90.jpeg")
cv::Mat contourOutput = img.clone();

// detect external contour(images will have noise, although example images doesn't have)

std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
cv::findContours(contourOutput, contours, RETR_EXTERNAL, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

int largest_area = 0;
int largest_contour_index = 0;
for (size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++) {
    double area = contourArea(contours[i]);

// copy the largest contour index
    if (area > largest_area) {
        largest_area = area;
        largest_contour_index = i;
}
}
//draw contours
drawContours(img, contours, largest_contour_index, Scalar(255, 0, 0),
             2);
// detect minimum area rect to get the angle and centre
cv::RotatedRect box = cv::minAreaRect(cv::Mat(contours[largest_contour_index]));
// take the box angle
double angle = box.angle;
if (angle < -45) {
    box.angle += 90;
}

angle = box.angle;
// create rotation matrix
cv::Mat rot_mat = cv::getRotationMatrix2D(box.center, angle, 1);

// Apply the transformation
cv::Mat rotated;
cv::warpAffine(img, rotated, rot_mat, img.size(), cv::INTER_CUBIC);
cv::Size box_size = box.size;

if (box.angle < -45.)
    std::swap(box_size.width, box_size.height);
// get the cropped image
cv::Mat cropped;
cv::getRectSubPix(rotated, box_size, box.center, cropped);

// Display the image
namedWindow("image2", WINDOW_NORMAL);
imshow("image2", cropped);
waitKey(0);
```

Comment: do you need the angle or the rotation center, or what is the problem? Have a look at my answer in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34237253/detect-centre-and-angle-of-rectangles-in-an-image-using-opencv/34285205#34285205

Comment: I am getting the angle, but i'm not sure how to always make it 180 degrees(horizontal to x-axis) :( As my image angles keeps varying. I am a newbie in this and i'm stuck from 1 day! Please help

Comment: if the angle is 10 degrees, rotate the image and the box by 170 degrees. if it is 33.3, rotate it by 146.7, and so on

Comment: i made it work like that! but how do i infer when to swap box.width and box.height. Should i have to find the contour again and draw boundingrect to crop ? This relates to same question to make the minAreaRect horizontal

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to compute the rotated bounding box angle using `minAreaRect` then deskew the image with `getRotationMatrix2D` and `warpAffine`. One final step is to rotate by 90 degrees if we are working with a vertical image. Here's the results with before (left) and after (right) and the angle of rotation:

[image]
[image]

```
-39.999351501464844
```

[image]
[image]

```
38.52387619018555
```

[image]
[image]

```
1.6167902946472168
```

[image]
[image]

```
1.9749339818954468
```

I implemented it in Python but you can adapt the same approach into C++

Code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load image, grayscale, and Otsu's threshold
image = cv2.imread('4.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Compute rotated bounding box
coords = np.column_stack(np.where(thresh > 0))
angle = cv2.minAreaRect(coords)[-1]

# Determine rotation angle
if angle < -45:
    angle = -(90 + angle)
else:
    angle = -angle
print(angle)

# Rotate image to deskew
(h, w) = image.shape[:2]
center = (w // 2, h // 2)
M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(center, angle, 1.0)
rotated = cv2.warpAffine(image, M, (w, h), flags=cv2.INTER_CUBIC, borderMode=cv2.BORDER_REPLICATE)

# Vertical image so rotate to horizontal
h, w, _ = rotated.shape
if h > w:
    rotated = cv2.rotate(rotated, cv2.ROTATE_90_CLOCKWISE)

cv2.imshow('rotated', rotated)
cv2.imwrite('rotated.png', rotated)
cv2.waitKey()
```