# emgucv angle detection for rectangle in csharp

Tags: c#, opencv, vector, emgucv, point

I am using following thread to perform angle detection for a rectangle image.
[Detect centre and angle of rectangles in an image using Opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34237253/detect-centre-and-angle-of-rectangles-in-an-image-using-opencv/34285205)

I am stuck at following piece of code.

```py
cv::Point2f edge1 = cv::Vec2f(rect_points[1].x, rect_points[1].y) - cv::Vec2f(rect_points[0].x, rect_points[0].y);
cv::Point2f edge2 = cv::Vec2f(rect_points[2].x, rect_points[2].y) - cv::Vec2f(rect_points[1].x, rect_points[1].y);

cv::Point2f usedEdge = edge1;
if(cv::norm(edge2) > cv::norm(edge1)) usedEdge = edge2;

cv::Point2f reference = cv::Vec2f(1,0); // horizontal edge

angle = 180.0f/CV_PI * acos((reference.x*usedEdge.x + reference.y*usedEdge.y) / (cv::norm(reference) *cv::norm(usedEdge)));
```

I am not able to figure out following few lines which i required to convert in  emgu csharp.

```py
cv::Point2f edge1 = cv::Vec2f(rect_points[1].x, rect_points[1].y) - cv::Vec2f(rect_points[0].x, rect_points[0].y);
cv::Point2f edge2 = cv::Vec2f(rect_points[2].x, rect_points[2].y) - cv::Vec2f(rect_points[1].x, rect_points[1].y);

angle = 180.0f/CV_PI * acos((reference.x*usedEdge.x + reference.y*usedEdge.y) / (cv::norm(reference) *cv::norm(usedEdge)));
```

```
if(cv::norm(edge2) > cv::norm(edge1)) usedEdge = edge2;
cv::Point2f reference = cv::Vec2f(1,0);
```

Can anyone help me how to resolve the same? Any help or suggestion will be highly appreciated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Point2f` here are simply points, having float precision properties of `X` and `Y`, being used to store 2D vectors of `I` and `J`. Their method if declaration is setting the edges to be the vector between two points, i.e. the delta between those two points. In C#, I would write this as:

```cs
float deltaX = rect_points[1].X - rect_points[0].X;
float deltaY = rect_points[1].Y - rect_points[0].Y;
PointF edge1 = new PointF(deltaX, deltaY);
```

**OR** of course...

```cs
PointF edge1 = new PointF(rect_points[1].X - rect_points[0].X, rect_points[1].Y - rect_points[0].Y);
PointF edge2 = new PointF(rect_points[2].X - rect_points[1].X, rect_points[2].Y - rect_points[1].Y);
```

These `PointF` are now the two vectors, or edges, that join at `rect_points[1]`. Next, `norm` is performed in order to compare the magnitude of the two. This is simply Pythagoras if we perform the same manually:

```cs
edge1Magnitude = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(edge1.X, 2) + Math.Pow(edge1.Y, 2));
edge2Magnitude = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(edge2.X, 2) + Math.Pow(edge2.Y, 2));
```

The longer of the edges, that with the greatest magnitude, is considered the "primary", or longer edge the rectangle:

```cs
PointF primaryEdge = edge1Magnitude > edge2Magnitude ? edge1 : edge2;
double primaryMagnitude = edge1Magnitude > edge2Magnitude ? edge1Magnitude : edge2Magnitude;
```

Finally, to find the angle between the `primaryEdge`, and a horizontal vector, `reference`. This is the acos, of the "Dot Product", of the two, or:

```cs
PointF reference = new PointF(1,0);
double refMagnitude = 1;
double thetaRads = Math.Acos(((primaryEdge.X * reference.X) + (primaryEdge.Y * reference.Y)) / (primaryMagnitude * refMagnitude));
double thetaDeg = thetaRads * 180 / Math.PI;
```

Now, `thetaDeg` is the angle between `edge1` and the horizontal, in degrees.

Comment: Please help for below lines.                                                                                                    
                                                                                
if(cv::norm(edge2) > cv::norm(edge1)) usedEdge = edge2;
cv::Point2f reference = cv::Vec2f(1,0);

Comment: Please help for cv::Point2f reference = cv::Vec2f(1,0);

Comment: @mBangali That should of been clear from the rest with a little effort from you, but I've now included it.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I already tried a lot before coming here.

Comment: No problem, I've also answered your other question :)

Comment: I am getting NaN for angle. I have posted code in question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216296/discussion-between-george-kerwood-and-mbangali).

Comment: Few images are of 180 degrees but detected as 90 degrees and vice versa happening.

Comment: The algorithm returns the angle between the longest edge of the rectangle and the x-axis. It's the same algorithm as the one you asked to copy.

Comment: I wanted to know is there anyway to upgrade algorithm to resolve  issue or I have to find something else.

Comment: What is “the issue”? Why is it wrong that they are at 90 degrees? Maybe ask a new question with some example image and an explanation of what result you want or were expecting.

Comment: New question added    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62550517/emgucv-pan-card-improper-skew-detection-in-c-sharp