# OpenCV contours orientation

Tags: python, opencv, geometry, contour

I need to know how oriented (clockwise/counterclockwise) contours after `cv2.findContours()` function.

I can do it by calling `cv2.contourArea()` with parameter `oriented`. But how do it more quickly? Maybe contours alwatys oriented in one direction?

Thanks!

Comment: Obtain straight rectangle around the contour and orient it based on the length and width of the obtained rectangle.

Comment: Maybe i'm not correct formulate my question. I need to know direction of contour bypass circout. The task is calculate outside normal to contour in every point.

Comment: a sample image and a sample of the expected output would help

Comment: [There](http://oi65.tinypic.com/30bzg5t.jpg) a scheme.

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33860887/5294258) you can find a sample c++ code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search an extreme point p on the contour, e.g. the right most point. Determine the predecessor (pred) and successor (succ) of p. Build two vectors a = pred - p, b = succ - p. Then the sign of the z-component of the cross product a x b tells you the orientation of the contour.

```
bool contourOrientationCW(const std::vector<cv::Point>& contour) {
    if (contour.size() >= 3) {
        cv::Point rm;   // right most point
        size_t rmIdx;   // index of right most point

        for (size_t i = 0; i < contour.size(); i++) {
            const cv::Point& p = contour[i];

            if (p.x > rm.x || p.x == rm.x && p.y > rm.y) {
                rm = p;
                rmIdx = i;
            }
        }
        size_t i = rmIdx - 1; if (i < 0) i = contour.size() - 1;
        const cv::Point& pred = contour[i];
        i = rmIdx + 1; if (i == contour.size()) i = 0;
        const cv::Point& succ = contour[i];

        Vec2i a = pred - rm, b = succ - rm;
        return a[0]*b[1] >= a[1]*b[0];
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: This, however, fails in the same cases where the `cv::contourArea` method fails, on contours with an area of zero (the cross product will always be the zero vector).